# Positioning of Pgfplot axis labels

Tags: pgfplots, labels

I'm trying to adjust the position of my axes labels and I'm having some trouble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={->},
    x label style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north, below=5mm},
    y label style={at={(current axis.above origin)},rotate=90,anchor=south east},
    xlabel={$u$ unemployment},
    ylabel={$\pi$ inflation}]
\addplot[black,samples=100,domain=0:1] {120*(1-x)^(1/3)-1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It may be that I don't understand the label style stuff, but I want the y label to be rotated and on the left of the y-axis (so it doesn't intersect with the ticks) and I want the x label to be below the x-axis (so it also doesn't run into ticks).  Also, is there a way to center the labels in those positions?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can control the position of labels accurately with

```
at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.03)}
```

The start of the axis is `0` and the end is `1`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={->},
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.1,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
    xlabel={$u$ unemployment},
    ylabel={$\pi$ inflation}]
\addplot[black,samples=100,domain=0:1] {120*(1-x)^(1/3)-1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 42):

You can use the `xlabel near ticks` and `ylabel near ticks` styles. These will automatically place the labels outside the ticks, whereas with Harish's solution you have to manually change the position to accommodate larger ticklabels. They are described in section **4.9.3 Labels** of the manual, and are defined as

```
\pgfplotsset{
  /pgfplots/xlabel near ticks/.style={
     /pgfplots/every axis x label/.style={
        at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel
     }
  },
  /pgfplots/ylabel near ticks/.style={
     /pgfplots/every axis y label/.style={
        at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},rotate=90,anchor=near ticklabel}
     }
  }
```

Code example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={->},
    ylabel near ticks,
    xlabel near ticks,
    xlabel={$u$ unemployment},
    ylabel={$\pi$ inflation}]
\addplot[black,samples=100,domain=0:1] {120*(1-x)^(1/3)-1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]