# Change color of individual bars in histogram of binomial distribution

Tags: pgfplots, color, bar-chart

With the help of [Positioning of Pgfplot axis labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142120/positioning-of-pgfplot-axis-labels) I managed to create histograms of binomial distributions. What I still need is to select some of the bars and fill them with a different color or mark them in another way in order to indicate probabilities like P(X < 4) or P(3 < X < 5).

This is what I've got so far.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={binom(\k,\n,\p)=\n!/(\k!*(\n-\k)!)*\p^\k*(1-\p)^(\n-\k);}
]
\begin{axis}[ymin=0, xmin=-0.5,axis lines=left,xlabel={$k$}, ylabel={$P(X=k)$}, x label style={at={(axis description cs:1,0.1)},anchor=north},
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.15,1)},rotate = -90, anchor=north}, ,
    samples at={0,...,12},
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=2
    },
    ybar=0pt, bar width=1
]
\addplot [fill=lightgray, fill opacity=0.5] {binom(x,12,0.4)}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related (for the binomial distribution): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198572/tikz-binomial-distribution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add another `\addplot` command with a different `samples at={...}` key:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={binom(\k,\n,\p)=\n!/(\k!*(\n-\k)!)*\p^\k*(1-\p)^(\n-\k);}
]
\begin{axis}[ymin=0, xmin=-0.5,axis lines=left,xlabel={$k$}, ylabel={$P(X=k)$}, x label style={at={(axis description cs:1,0.1)},anchor=north},
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.15,1)},rotate = -90, anchor=north}, ,
    samples at={0,...,12},
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=2
    },
    ybar=0pt, bar width=1, bar shift=0pt
]
\addplot [fill=gray!25] {binom(x,12,0.4)}; 
\addplot [fill=orange, samples at={0,...,4}] {binom(x,12,0.4)};
\addplot [fill=cyan, samples at={7}] {binom(x,12,0.4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```