# Updated Miktex, and tikz does not rotate the y-axis properly

Tags: tikz-pgf

I updated Miktex and also pgfplots to the latest version today. But now i have a Problem with pgfplots. It seems it doesn't like the rotation of the y axis label.

I tried the 32 bit Version and also the 64bit Version of Miktex as well as different Latex Editors. So this is the example of the Manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title=With \texttt{near ticklabel},
ylabel={$f(x)=x$},
every axis y label/.style={
at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel,
},
clip=false,
ylabel style={draw=red},
yticklabel style={draw=red},
]
\addplot {x};
\fill (yticklabel cs:0.5) circle(2pt);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When i rotate the y label via

```
every axis y label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel,rotate=90,
    },
```

it is set to some weird Position, as shown in the Image. Are there any suggestions where to begin to search?

[[image: Compiled Example]]

I'm using Latex-PS-PDF for compiling, and normaly the Texnic-Center with UTF-8 encoding

Comment: Hi, welcome. Same problem as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/501617/ perhaps? If you can go straight to PDF via pdf/xe/lualatex it might work.

Comment: Hi. Thx for the fast answer. your are correct, that is exactly the same problem. As one can see in my image, the label is positioned correctly. Just the text inside the label is way off

Comment: Solution is: revert to pgf 3.1.3, if possible. I did, and just tried multiple tests with many different files containing similar tikzpicture code, and they all worked perfectly.

Comment: Test with recent MikTeX installation using `pdflatex` and `xelatext` gives correct result.

Comment: Neither of which is a robust solution if your document includes .eps files (typically, images), unfortunately. I still submit best generic solution is to keep using pgf 3.1.3, if possible.

Comment: So at the moment i changed my workflow to pdflatex. Ok, it does work, but now i have doubled the amount of files, since i use a lot of eps. But it is still better then correcting the diagrams or use another program like gnuplot. Thx for the help