# pgfplots: `x dir = reverse` --> Problem with x-label (`xlabel`) placement

Tags: pgfplots

### Issue

- I use `x dir = reverse` to **reverse** the direction of the **x-axis** (arrow points to the **left**).
- Is there an *easy* way to also **move the x label** to the "correct" position (mirrored regarding the y-axis compared to the "normal" case)?

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

% http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = middle,
        xlabel = {x label},
        ylabel = {y label},
        x dir = reverse, % <-- Important
    ]
    % use TeX as calculator:
    \addplot {x^2 - x +4};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Related

[Positioning of Pgfplot axis labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142120/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the position with `xlabel style={at={}}`. The left of the plot is `current axis.left of origin`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

% http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = middle,
        xlabel = {x label},
        xlabel style={at={(current axis.left of origin)},anchor=south west},
        ylabel = {y label},
        x dir = reverse, % <-- Important
    ]
    % use TeX as calculator:
    \addplot {x^2 - x +4};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Source: PGFPLOTS manual section 4.9.9 *Axis Lines*.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And especially thanks for mentioning the source.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I am in a difficult time zone.

Comment: *"difficult" should be "different" :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I was wondering indeed what a difficult time zone could be :)