# pgfplots: 3D Axes System. Reverse xlabel

Tags: pgfplots

- This question is about a 3D coordinate system in `pgfplots`.
- **Problem 1:** I want to have the `xlabel` on the "other side" (tried `x dir = reverse,` already).
- **Problem 2:** This is less important (nice to have). I want to have the perspective as in my hand drawing (a perfect cross: y and z, and the 3rd dimension, depth, is indicated by a 45 degree line: x), see "Remark" in the hand drawing. **Additional Remark:** In the hand drawing I use different labels (this is a typical automotive coordinate system). But I can fake that by just naming the `xlabel` `"y"` and so on.

---

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width = 80mm,
        height = 80mm,
        axis lines = center,
        no marks,
        axis line style = {latex-latex, ultra thick}, % 
        unit vector ratio = 1 1 1,
        ticks = none,
        xmin = -1,
        xmax = 1,
        ymin = -1,
        ymax = 1,   
        zmin = -1,
        zmax = 1,   
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$,
        zlabel = $z$,
    ]
    % No plot
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

### Related

- [pgfplots: `x dir = reverse` --> Problem with x-label (`xlabel`) placement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/582281)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you first request you can use `x dir=reverse` swap the position of `xmin` and `xmax`.  However, this does not move the `xlabel`.  Here you can use

```
every axis x label/.style={at=(ticklabel cs:-0.07)}
```

The `ticklabel cs:` starts at `0` at one end of the axis and ends at `1` at the other, so `0.07` puts the label just beyond the "beginning" of the axis.  Putting this together, and adding a plot that shows the positive first quadrant for x and y, and using the same idea to adjust the `ylabel`, we get

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width = 80mm,
        height = 80mm,
        axis lines = center,
        no marks,
        axis line style = {latex-latex, ultra thick}, %
        unit vector ratio = 1 1 1,
        ticks = none,
        xmin = -1,
        xmax = 1,
        ymin = -1,
        ymax = 1,
        zmin = -1,
        zmax = 1,
        x dir=reverse,
        every axis x label/.style={at={(xticklabel cs:-0.07)}},
        every axis y label/.style={at={(yticklabel cs:1.07)}},
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$,
        zlabel = $z$,
    ]
    \addplot3 [surf, z buffer=sort, samples=15, variable=\u,
    variable y=\v, domain=0:1, y domain=0:1, opacity=0.5]
    ({u},{v},0);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Unfortuantely `pgfplots` does not support perspective drawing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know which setting for the x label position is used by default?

Comment: And thanks for showing me that there is no built-in, automatic, way to change the label's position as a result of the reverse option etc. I was assuming that I miss a magic option.

Comment: Happy to hear this was useful.  You can get the default/current value by writing `every axis x label/.show code` which for me gives `near ticklabel align=inside,at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, anchor=near ticklabel opposite}`