# Creating a sign diagram and adding labels for it on each side of a number line

Tags: pgfplots, pdftex

I am creating a calculus sign diagram by creating a number line and labeling each side of it - the right side with an `x` and the left side with a `y'`.  Above appropriate intervals I want to add plus and minus signs.

In the example below I want the `x` label to be on the right side of the arrowhead vertically centered with the line instead of above the line.  On the left-hand side I'd like to add a `y'` vertically centered the same way.  How can I accomplish this?  By adding a node?

Above the interval `[-3,0]` I'd like to center a plus sign over it to show that the derivative is positive there.  How can I add the plus sign like this?

I run `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=none,
    xmin=-4.75, xmax=3.75, xlabel = $x$, xtick={-3,0,2},
    width = 10cm]
    \addplot[
        domain=-3:2,
        samples=800,
        smooth,
        thick,
        blue,
    ] {0};
    \addplot[
        domain=-4.75:-3,
        samples=800,
        smooth,
        thick,
        yellow,
    ] {0};
    \addplot[
        domain=2:3.75,
        samples=800,
        smooth,
        thick,
        yellow,
    ] {0};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to typeset math in my posting?  Dollars signs/LaTeX no longer seem to work.

Comment: You don't `;-)` Math rendering is deactivated on the site. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1272/82917

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Adaptations

- use `(axis description cs:x,y)` for positioning of `x` and `y'` (see [Positioning of Pgfplot axis labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142120/123129))

  - because here are multiple labels I use nodes for this (instead of `xlabel`)
- use `(x,y)` for positioning the `+` sign (using the coordinates of the axis environment)

  - as [hpekristiansen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/8650/hpekristiansen) said in his comment `(axis cs:x,y)` is now the default, so one can use `(x,y)` instead (since pgfplots 1.11, see [pgfplots manual](https://ftp.fau.de/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf): 2.2.1 New Optional Features)
- add option `clip=false` (so the nodes outside of the plot are visible)
- add option `axis line style={yellow}` (instead of manually drawing those yellow lines)
- `addplot`: remove option `smooth` and reduce `samples` to `2` as it's just a straight line

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        clip=false,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=none,
        axis line style={yellow},
        xmin=-4.75, xmax=3.75, xtick={-3,0,2},
        width = 10cm]
        \addplot[
            domain=-3:2,
            samples=2,
            thick,
            blue,
        ] {0};
        \node[at={(axis description cs:1,.5)},anchor=west] {$x$};
        \node[at={(axis description cs:0,.5)},anchor=east] {$y'$};
        \node[at={(-1.5,0)},anchor=south] {$+$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: To center the `+` over the interval I would use `axis cs:-1.5,0` instead?

Comment: Oh, yeah. I must have read that wrong. I changed it.

Comment: +1. Do not use `axis cs:` -it is default since long time ago. Alternative: `\path (-3,0) -- node[above]{$+$} (0,0);`

Comment: I added `thick` to keep the axis the same thickness as the blue plot: `axis line style={thick,yellow}`.

Comment: @hpekristiansen `axis cs:` seems to work just fine.  What problem does it cause?

Comment: It causes no problem. But since `pgfplots` 1.11 a position `(x,y)` is interpreted as `(axis cs:x,y)`. Therefore, one can use that shorter notation. I added that point to my answer. (Only if you have to use an old version of `pgfplots` (< 1.11) you couldn't use that short notation.)